# Wordpress File Attachments

Tags: wordpress, attachment, gravityforms

I am setting up a custom document mamangement system in Wordpress. I have setup a Custom Post type to hold document topics, and gravity form plugin to manage creating forms.  At this time I'm using comment attachment plugin to upload files and attachments to the custom post type.  But there are different types of attachments, such as worksheet and application PDF files.

What would be a good way to manage file uploads and attaching pdf documents to a custom post type?